# Can you require that two "any" types resolve to the same explicit type in Typescript?

Tags: typescript

Example: i have a function that sorts an array. It takes an input array and produces a sorted output array.

`function sort(input: any[]): any[]{  // ... }`

I want the input and outputs to share the same type (e.g. `number[]` or `string[]`) but i don't know what type of array i'll receive in advance.

Is there a way to enforce this using Typescript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use generics:

```
function sort<T extends unknown>(input: T[]): T[]{
  // ...implementation
}
const arr = [1, 2];
const result = sort(arr);
```

Then `result` will be typed as `number[]`.

Note that if you use the built-in `.sort` function, you'll be mutating the existing array, not creating an entirely new one, so keep that in mind - if you want to return a new array, you'll have to clone the old array first, otherwise you might confuse users of the function who see their input get mutated.